# Insert static blocks within a PHP loop

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, loops

**I'm trying to insert 2 static div's inside a PHP loop**, specifically one at the very beginning of the loop and one at the very end.

These 2 div's must appear within their corresponding `.row` parent which currently wraps around every 3 DIV's. How can I do this?

**EDIT**
Here's an image to describe what I need, the pink blocks are the manually inserted div's that will have different content to the blue divs. Those blue divs are just WP posts:

[image]

**Here's my PHP, currently this creates** 4 columns within the first and last rows where it should just be 3 columns:

```
<?php static $c=1;
      $subs = new WP_Query( array( 'post_parent' => 14, 'post_type' => 'page' ));
      if( $subs->have_posts() ) : while( $subs->have_posts() ) : $subs->the_post(); ?>

           <?php if (($c % 3) === 1) {
             // This creates part of the wrapper .row div
             echo "<div class='row'>";
           } ?>

           <?php 
           if ($c == 1) {?>
             <div class="col_4 card bar">
              first card that is manually inserted with different content
             </div>
           <?php } ?>

              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="col_4 card bar no-pad <?php if($c % 3 == 0) { echo 'last'; } ?>">
                 <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {?>
                 <div class="feature-image c-1">
                       <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
                 </div>
                 <?php } ?>
                 <div class="excerpt-wrap">
                    This is a post from within Wordpress
                 </div>
              </a>

           <?php if ($c == 6) {?>
                <div class="col_4 card bar">
                 Last card that is manually inserted with different content
                </div>
           <?php } ?>

           <?php if (($c % 4) === 3) {
             echo "</div>";
           }?>
     <?php $c++; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

**EDIT**
This is the HTML structure I'd like to achieve:

```
<!-- very first row -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- This is a static block followed by the very first two worpdress posts-->
  <div class="static-block"></div>

  <a href="#" class="wp-post"></a>
  <a href="#" class="wp-post"></a>
</div>

<!-- I could have 3 or 30 wordpress posts repeating this format -->
<div class="row">
  <a href="#" class="wp-post"></a>
  <a href="#" class="wp-post"></a>
  <a href="#" class="wp-post"></a>
</div>

<!-- very last row -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- These are the very two worpdress posts followed by a static block -->
  <a href="#" class="wp-post"></a>
  <a href="#" class="wp-post"></a>

  <div class="static-block"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @treegarden I've added a image to hopefully make things clearer

Comment: And what's not working in your code?

Comment: @treegarden I've also added this to the questions, where I've introduced my PHP. Currently 4 rows are being added instead of just 3

Comment: @treegarden I've also uploaded the HTML structure I'm trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
    $c = 1;
    $subs = new WP_Query(array('post_parent' => 14, 'post_type' => 'page'));
    if ($subs->have_posts()) :
    ?>
        <div class='row'>
            <?php 
                while ($subs->have_posts()) : $subs->the_post();
                if (($c % 3) == 0 || $c == 3):
            ?>
        </div><div class='row'>
        <?php
                endif;
        ?>
        <?php
            if ($c == 1):
        ?>
            <div class="col_4 card bar">
            first card that is manually inserted with different content
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="col_4 card bar no-pad <?php if ($c % 3 == 0) { echo 'last'; } ?>">
        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
            <div class="feature-image c-1">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
            <div class="excerpt-wrap">
                This is a post from within Wordpress
            </div>
        </a>

        <?php if ($c == 7) { ?>
            <div class="col_4 card bar">
                Last card that is manually inserted with different content
            </div>
        <?php } ?>


    <?php 
        $c++;
        endwhile; 
    ?>
    </div>                        
<?php
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>
```

> if have more then 7 page and u want to static block add on last just
>   change 7  to post count value **( $c == $sub->post_count)**

[image]

Comment: This works brilliantly. Just what I wanted! Thanks Ravi!

Comment: Quick question: Using your code, how can I set a global counter for ALL blocks?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: sorry, it seems that I saw your post before you uploaded the pictures of the wireframe.**

It's not so clear to me the goal of your code. But, what I understand is you need to generate an structure like this:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='static'>
  </div>
  <div class='static'>
  </div>

  #here the loop will create
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <div class='static'>
  </div>
  <div class='static'>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this will be duplicated for as many *i* in your *while* you have.

if that is what you need, then I think what you need to do is count 1,2,3 with your $c variable. Everytime you are in $c = 1 print the first 2 static divs, and when you are in $c = 3 print the final 2 static divs. Reset $c to 1 when you reach $c = 3 and include a conditional asking if its the last item and its $c != 3 so you print out the last 2 static divs.

Comment: After having seen the picture you just uploaded then solution I would give remains the same, just counting 4 instead of 3 and adding 1 div at the beginning and end. Hope it is what you needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. See my updated question with ideal HTML structure

Comment: in that case you need to take the length of the array.. rest 2 (for the first row) and divide the remaining by 3. The result will be the amount of raws you will have in the middle (where no static divs are printed out).. and the rest from that division will be the remaining 1 or 2 divs (which you will round up with ceil(i*3) ) and you will have for the last row, to which you will need to count and when you are in that position you will know you have to print out the last static div.

what you have to think thru is what happens if the number of items is 32. What happens to the last static item?

Comment: Would you be able to provide some sample code? I'm not entirely sure I get what you mean.